# Get the PC date from an app in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

After trying many googlings I can not find any thing related to this problem. What I wanted is getting my PC's date not the Google's server date.
I did try by using `URLFetchApp` to make a HTTP request with a hope that some JavaScript can be executed and then I can have a nice PC's date as the response but it was not so simple. I do not really have no idea how to make some progress right now so may you can give some hints?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You're going to need this:

(1) Set up a URI on the app side to retrieve the data

(2) use a tiny bit of javascript in your client side to capture Date, and translate it to JSON.

(3) Send that JSON to the URI.

This will be a lot easier if you can make the client initiate it, say at the time your page loads, but it *can* be done by having the server side request it.

Details of how to handle this depend somewhat on what Javascript library etc you use.  I like jQuery, which would make the second step something like `jQuery.toJSON(new Date())`.

Comment: Could you give more infos in step 3 ? Do i need to export a new json file ?

Comment: Read up on httpXMLRequest.  You're either going to want to put the JSON into the URI as an argument, or you will want to create a PUT request.